# How to convert json to required format

Tags: python, json, google-visualization

I am trying to visualize some data using google charts. I am fetching this data by firing a query on a publicly available data. I am doing this in python. Here is the code that I have

```
query_string = 'SELECT state, count(*) FROM [{0}] GROUP by state;'.format(_DATABASE_NAME)
births = self.run_query(query_string, filename='data/states.json')
# rows = births[u'rows']
#logging.info(births)
ages= []

states.insert(0, ('Age','No of occurences'))
logging.info(json.encode(ages))
context = {"states": json.encode(ages)}
```

After firing the query this is what I get in the JSON file

```
[
    {
        "f0_": "6170247",
        "mother_age": "31"
    },
    {
        "f0_": "6876756",
        "mother_age": "30"
    },
    {
        "f0_": "8271245",
        "mother_age": "26"
    }
]
```

To visualize it I would need this data in the following format -

```
[
   ['Age', 'No of occurences'],
   ['31', '6170247'],
   ['30', '6876756'],
   .....
]
```

How do I do this? Also I just realized that the google chart might need the ages to be sorted? What might be the best way to do that? In the query itself?

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [
    {
        "f0_": "6170247",
        "mother_age": "31"
    },
    {
        "f0_": "6876756",
        "mother_age": "30"
    },
    {
        "f0_": "8271245",
        "mother_age": "26"
    }
]
```

---

**Edit:** As @Matthew mentioned if you have data in json file, you can use json module to load this data.

```
import json
with open(<path_to_json>) as fname:
    data = json.load(fname)
```

---

**Transforming data**

Iterate over the list of dictionaries i.e. `data` and add them into a list

```
new_list = []
for item in data:
    new_list.append([data["mother_age"], data["f0_"]])

# new_list --> [['31', '6170247'], ['30', '6876756'], ['26', '8271245']]
```

**Sorting the list**

You can sort this list in place

```
new_list.sort(key=lambda sublist: sublist[0])
# new_list --> [['26', '8271245'], ['30', '6876756'], ['31', '6170247']]
```

Or create a new sorted list using `sorted` function, `new_list` will not be changed

```
final_list = sorted(new_list, key=lambda sublist: sublist[0])
# new_list --> [['31', '6170247'], ['30', '6876756'], ['26', '8271245']]
# final_list --> [['26', '8271245'], ['30', '6876756'], ['31', '6170247']]
```

Or you can use [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) instead of `sorted`

```
from operator import itemgetter
final_list = sorted(new_list, key=itemgetter(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the using the `json` module and then iterate over it to produce the structure you want:

```
import json

with open(<json-file>) as jfile:
    jdata = json.load(jfile)

data = [['Age', 'No of occurences']]
for d in jdata:
    data.append([d['mother_age'], d['f0_']])
```

It would definitely be better to sort the data in the query but it's also easily done with the json data:

```
for d in sorted(jdata, key=lambda x: x['mother_age']):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a dictionary and a loop over Json to get your desired format, like:

```
data = [
    {
        "f0_": "6170247",
        "mother_age": "31"
    },
    {
        "f0_": "6876756",
        "mother_age": "30"
    },
    {
        "f0_": "8271245",
        "mother_age": "26"
    }
]
well_formated_data = []
well_formated_data.append(['Age','No of occurences'])

for elem in data:
    new_array = []
    new_array.append(elem['mother_age'])
    new_array.append(elem['f0_'])
    well_formated_data.append(new_array)
```

I check the code and it works, I get this result:

```
well_formated_data = [['Age', 'No of occurences'], ['31', '6170247'], ['30', '6876756'], ['26', '8271245']]
```